# GDAL/ogr2ogr ( to convert osm to shapefile)

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, convert, ogr

I use GDAL / ogr2ogr to convert osm to shapefile but I get an error.

C:\Users\alo>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" outputdir "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm"

**Warning 1**: Cannot find osmconf.ini configuration file

**ERROR 1**: Could not parse configuration file for OSM import
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm' with the following drivers.
  ->`netCDF'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  ->`JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
  ->`DB2ODBC'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'

Comment: Either you do not have the file "osmconf.ini" in at all or it is not found from the file path. How did you install and run GDAL? How did you set the environment variables? What gdal version do you have and does "ogrinfo --formats" list the OSM driver?

Comment: i have this file osmconf,ini in C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data. And i installed first latest Version  then uninstalled and i installed GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20. And i run it wiwth command line. And i adde path C:\Program Files\GDAL. Thanks for you help

Comment: Do you also that gdal-data directory in the path?

Comment: Thanks very much i already added this path and still not wworking.

Comment: do you know Maybe how can i convert gokg to shape file

Comment: If you stil get the "Cannot find osmconf.ini configuration file" error then your environment is not set correctly. I recommend to download a zip file from gisinternals.con, unzip and run the "sdkshell.bat" batch file and it will work. Another option is to install from OSGeo4W and open the OSGeo4W shell which set the environment right.

Comment: i installed OSGeo4W and it worked good  but also i get another error ( i get all files with siee 1KB) and this error in Shell  : 
C:\Users\Public\Desktop\OSGeo4W>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" outputdir "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm"
0Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'admin_level' to 'admin_leve'
ERROR 6: Geometry type of `Geometry Collection' not supported in shapefiles.  Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH.

Comment: They are not errors but limitations of the shapefile format. Field names can't be longer than 10 chacters long, and geometry collections are not supported but the "other_relations" layer in OSM data contains them. Convert to GeoPackage of SpatiaLite for avoiding those problems, or convert layer by layer and forget other_relations. But I think that this is not the rigth forum as a teaching platform.

Comment: Thanks alot i convert it gpkg but i Need shapefile. How can i then convert gpkg to shapefile.: Thanksfor your help

Comment: Read https://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html and other manuals and convert layer by layer except other_relations than can't be saved into shapefile. Example `C:\Users\alo>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_points.shp "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm" points`. But I really think this gets off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

`ogr2ogr` does not find the `osmconf.ini`. Surprisingly :-)
As stated in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#configuration you can define an alternate path with the `OSM_CONFIG_FILE` configuration option.

Assuming your `osmconf.ini` is located in `C:\Users\alo\osmconf.ini` your command will be:

```
C:\Users\alo>ogr2ogr --config OSM_CONFIG_FILE C:\Users\alo\osmconf.ini -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.shp" "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm" points
```

If you can not find an `osmconf.ini` on your installation, use this one: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/osm/data/osmconf.ini